# (Python) Пожалуйста, помогите найти ошибку в коде

Tags: python

Все время пишет что имя не может быть меньне 1 символа, исправьте это пожалуйста!

```
import os
import random as rand

nick = ""
inpt = ""


def choose():
    print("Здравствуй, ", nick, "!")
    print("Пожалуйста, выбери тип бизнеса:")
    print("1 - Игровая индустрия")
    print("2 - Кафе, рестораны")
    print("3 - Продуктовый магазин")
    print("4 - Подпольная торговля(посредник)")
    menu()


def menu():
    inpt = input("Ввод > ")


def chckname():
    if nick.__len__() <= 1:
        print("Имя не может быть меньше 1 символа!")
        name()
        else:
            choose()


def name():
    print("Напишите свое имя:")
    nick = input("Ввод >> ")
    print("Вы ввели имя", nick)
    chckname()


name()
```

Comment: Читай про области действия и видимости  переменных.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

лучше `nick` передавать в функцию. если не передать то программа думает что `nick` это пустая строка

место `nick.__len__()` лучше писать `len(nick)`

```
def chckname(nick):
    if len(nick) <= 1:
        print("Имя не может быть меньше 1 символа!")
        name()
    else:
        choose()


def name():
    print("Напишите свое имя:")
    nick = input("Ввод >> ")
    print("Вы ввели имя", nick)
    chckname(nick)
```

Comment: @BlackLightHack-lox100, если ответ вам помог, то пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой, так другие форумчане поймут что вопрос решён